# Undefined Type for JFrame

Tags: java

so i was getting a error in Eclipse for my java program to make a new JFrame and i couldnt quiet figure out my it wouldnt load the correct data to set it to be visable and to set the title, location, size, and what it should do when someone closes the JFrame so id like some help if i could please

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class JFrame 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        JFrame JF = new JFrame();       
        JF.setTitle("Test");
        JF.setSize(400, 200);
        JF.setLocation(200, 300);
        JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JF.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: hen you ask about an error, **always** post the complete and exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You named your own class `JFrame`, thus hiding the standard `javax.swing.JFrame` class.

Choose another name for your class.